# Perl hash referencing itself at declaration

Tags: perl

When declaring a Perl hash, I'm wondering if it's possible to use a value that was assigned earlier in the declaration.

I'd like to do the equivalent of this, all in one shot:

```
my %H   = (something => generateString());
$H{foo} = $H{something} . "/FOO",
$H{bar} = $H{something} . "/BAR",
```

I can imagine something like this:

```
my %H = (
   something => generateString(),
   foo       => $_{something} . "/FOO",
   bar       => $_{something} . "/BAR",
);
```

EDIT: To be clear, I don't care about an actual *reference* to `$H{something}` (i.e. changing `$H{something}` later shouldn't affect `$H{foo}`). I'd just like to get its value into the string concatenations.

Comment: Why not just `my $something = generateString(); my %hash = ( something => $something, foo => $something . "/FOO", bar => $something . "/BAR" );` ?

Comment: Same reason I don't want to do the other way I proposed to do this - I'm just curious if this is possible

Comment: Usually when someone is "just curious if this is possible," it means they want to do it that way, even if doing so makes their code less readable and harder to maintain.

Comment: I don't understand the mechanism that creates hashes, clearly. I guess the whole RHS is created before the LHS gets to see it.. I'm just saying the `something => generateString()` code runs before `foo =>..`, so I'm curious about whether it's been assigned anywhere.

Comment: It's not a question of the RHS seeing the LSH. You can't assign to the LHS until you finish evaluating the RHS.

Comment: I didn't intend the question to be "how to best populate this hash" but rather, "can I get at values that were resolved earlier in the declaration"

Comment: After the declaration, it'll be `$H{something}`.

Comment: (You mean "assignment".) Yes, but you want it before. There's nothing in $H{something}. So the question stands

Comment: `generateString()` has certainly already run though by the time we get to the `foo => ...` bit though.. it's got to live somewhere!

Comment: So you want `my %H = ( something => generateString(), foo => stack(2) . "/FOO", bar => stack(4) . "/BAR" );`. yeah... no.

Comment: I figured given Perl's tendency to have hidden variables all over the place, it's possible that it would be accessible somehow. Don't make me feel like it was a silly question :)

Comment: `my %H = ( something => generateString(), foo => $STACK[-2] . "/FOO", bar => $STACK[-4] . "/BAR" );` wouldn't be any better.

Comment: You seem to think the intent of the question is to inform good coding practice. It isn't. I'm merely trying to understand stuff that goes on behind the scenes during a hash declaration/assignment.

Comment: You asked how to do it. I showed you that it could be done, and I explained why noone's done it. I did not recommend any coding practices. As for wanting to understand how things happen in the background, why did you accept the answer that doesn't explain anything at all in favour of the answer that explains exactly what you claim to want to understand?

Comment: @ikegami your answer shows a simple solution to populate the hash, which wasn't what I was looking for. I really wanted to know if there was a way to use hash elements _before they're assigned to the LHS_, which mpapec's answer shows.

Comment: To be fair, mpapec's answer doesn't use the sort of mechanism I was expecting, but I think it clearly addresses the original question.

Comment: Hash question are always good question because - ahem - [hashes are the "key" to perl](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=90610) and to perl OO and Moose etc. For the record, I am not that "advanced" but it was a classic by Sriram Srinivasan, Advanced Perl Programming, O'Reilly, 1997 that helped me learn the most in the shortest time. Well that combined with @ikegami mpapec and others here on SO.

Comment: @ikegami Perhaps I'm misusing LHS and RHS (and declaration and assignment, for that matter), but it hits the spirit of what I was looking for. I didn't mean to get you all fired up :)

Comment: @ajwood, what? mpapec's solution doesn't show that at all. His second snippet is just a complicated version of mine. It does `my $something = generateString();
my %H = (
   something => $something,
   foo       => "$something/FOO",
   bar       => "$something/BAR",
);`. You can't claim his code is ok and mine isn't since they're both storing the result of `generateString()` in a temporary variable, then referencing that variable. You obviously don't understand what he posted, yet you claim it's an explanation of what you wanted?

Comment: @ikegami to me, mpapec's answer looks like a way to add some crazy wrapping around the hash declaration to do precisely what I asked in the question.

Comment: Again, that's not what he did. Don't you realize that mpapec did `my %h = ( something => generateString() );
    my %H = (
       something => $h{something},
       foo       => "$h{something}/FOO",
       bar       => "$h{something}/BAR",
    );

`? That's exactly what I did.

Comment: Contrary to what you claim mp4pec's code does NOT show "a way to use hash elements before they're assigned to the LHS". He used an external variable to store `generateString()` just like I did. You realize there's two hashes, right? I'm sorry you're still confused, but I gotta go.

Comment: Sure, but in the accepted answer, that's all buried in the loop.. Like I said before, I wasn't interested in "the best way to populate the hash" but rather what crazy Perl stuff will do what I asked. I upvoted both answers, but since I can only accept one, I think mpapec's is closer to answering the question.

Comment: That's not true. It's the same code, so his doesn't do what you ask if mine doesn't. Mine also has an explanation as to why it's impossible.

Comment: I'm not. I don't care whose answer you accept. I'm just trying to help you realize the code doesn't do what you claim it does. You've repeatedly saying something that's completely wrong, but you really don't seem interested learning 1) the answer to your original question, and 2) why what you are saying is false, despite saying that was your primary goal.

Comment: @ikegami I appreciate your effort - apologies for being disagreeable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my %H = (something => generateString());
%H = (%H, 
   foo => $H{something} ."/FOO",
   bar => $H{something} ."/BAR",
);
```

seems reasonable, but if you want it in one shot at ANY cost,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

%{ $_->{hash} } = (
   something => $_->{thing},
   foo       => "$_->{thing}/FOO",
   bar       => "$_->{thing}/BAR",
)
for {hash => \my %H, thing => generateString()};
```

which can be translated to more verbose version,

```
my %H;
local $_ = {hash => \%H, thing => generateString()};

%{ $_->{hash} } = (
   something => $_->{thing},
   foo       => "$_->{thing}/FOO",
   bar       => "$_->{thing}/BAR",
);
```

Comment: This is using `thing` as a placeholder until the string is generated, right? I'm really trying to figure out if I can access already-assigned hash values _while_ *that* hash is being constructed.

Comment: @ikegami it will be visible.

Comment: This is the hackiest bit of code, which I would advise not to do.  The ANY cost, should really go into more detail.

Comment: @vol7ron what do you suggest? OP was already advised not to follow such practice.

Comment: Nothing against mpapec for correctly answering the question, but unless there is a specific reason you can't use an additional variable, I think Ikegami's answer to using a temporary variable would be key here.  Not only does it reduce the amount of characters use to keep it concise, but it is much more legible in what is happening.  You see where the variable is defined and if a bug pops up, where to fix it.  Additionally, I think it is much more efficient but that is probably negligible in this example.

Comment: @vol7ron that is why I wrote first solution, where everything is in place and no temporary variable is needed.

Comment: @mpapec yes but this is doing double the work - two assignments for multiple keys, not only that, I think it also has to destruct the hash into a list in order for that to happen.  I typically only do that method when I want to create a new hash, or override keys with some other hash who's key/val pairs may be dynamic (e.g., when overwriting default settings).  I generally get flack for that because of the coworkers that may not understand Perl as much as Ruby or Python, so you also have to have thick skin to deal with those convos.

Comment: @vol7ron this happens when you have this type of question; an answer that tries to provide even when that means jumping through the hoops.

Comment: Yes, I'm also guilty of asking them, so I shouldn't be too hypocritical.  Just making sure @ajwood knows what he's asking.  I'm sure I probably asked the same thing at one time and really what I wanted to know was how to reference the hash during it's constructor.  After the first key/val pair is assigned, I would think that the object would be created, but even if it is internally, it is not exposed and thus cannot be done.

Comment: I definitely don't plan to use to this construct! I was just writing out a hash and wondering if it could be done..

Answer (score 5):

You seem to think there are two assignment operators in

```
%H = ( a=>1, b=>$H{a} );
```

There isn't. Keep in mind the above is identical to

```
%H = ( 'a', 1, 'b', $H{a} );
```

There's one assignment operator, and before you can perform the assignment, you need to know what is going to be assignment.

What I'm saying is that the real problem with `%H = ( a=>1, b=>$H{a} );` isn't one of scope; the real problem is that nothing been assigned to `%H` when you do `$H{a}`<sup>[1]</sup>. As such, `$_{a}` makes more sense than `$H{a}`.

The solution is simple:

```
my $something = generateString();
my %H = (
   something => $something,
   foo       => "$something/FOO",
   bar       => "$something/BAR",
);
```

---

1. `%H` hasn't even been created yet!

Answer (score 2):

As ikegami says, there is only one assignment operation; it is executed after the entire right hand side is evaluated.

A couple alternatives:

```
my %H = map {;
    'something' => $_,
    'foo' => "$_/FOO",
    'bar' => "$_/BAR",
} generateString();
```

and

```
use Memoize;
memoize('generateString');
my %H = (
    'something' => scalar(generateString()),
    'foo' => generateString() . '/FOO',
    'bar' => generateString() . '/BAR',
);
```

(scalar needed because otherwise, memoize will make separate calls for list and scalar context.)

Comment: plus 1 for map, best so far

Comment: @mpapec: no, absolutely the best way so far is ikegami's answer; I can see using map in slightly different circumstances, though, which is why I showed it.

Comment: The biggest abuse of `map` yet, I love it.  And no… don't use it!  I was also considering to mention `memoize`, but wouldn't it turn a function that generates a random string into a static one? So to implement that, you would have to pass some sort of argument that you want the function to always return the same response for.  Perhaps the null argument would be it in this case, but then you'd always need to include an argument elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to do the definition as part of the assignments:

```
my %H = (
   something => ( local our $str=generateString() ),
   foo       => qq{$str/FOO},
   bar       => qq{$str/BAR}
);
```

There are two things to consider:

1. Notice the use of `local our` instead of `my`
2. I advise against this.  For many reasons; if not for best coding practices, but for bugs that may be introduced.

I feel that defining a variable outside the hash definition (as shown in Ikegami's answer) is the best way to go for many reasons, but I realize that's also not the question being asked.  The answer to the question is that a hash cannot be referenced before it is created and during creation it is not exposed within the constructor.

Comment: @ikeagmi I was curious what you meant be using `local`, as I could not see it being done without the use of `our`

Comment: `local` doesn't create variables, so you yeah, you still need `our`. Have you noticed the edits?

Comment: I guess my only need for local has been when overriding special variables, which are already defined. I saw your changes once I  saw the comments go missing. I was hoping you would also make the change of "constructor" to something more correct. I think I was aiming for the assignment value, or something the user can actually control.